# javascript - auto refresh to php page has different results when on LTE and not wifi

Tags: javascript, ajax

I just discovered this issue today and I cant figure out. Basically when I am on wifi everything seems to run fine. As soon as I get on LTE (or off wifi) then I get some weird results. I am attaching some pictures to this as well so you can see what normal and not normal looks like. Basically there are random numbers and letters appearing all over the place. When I get on wifi everything stops.

Normal (On wifi)

[image]

Not Normal (Off wifi)

[image]

Yes I know it looks like iMessage but its not. This is for internal use only.

First I have a part of my javascript code that auto refreshes to a `chat.php` page which is the chat portion of the screen and does this every 3 seconds. The reason I auto refresh is that it calls a database and will show any new messages. I have messed with the timing for the auto refresh both increasing and decreasing it and still had same results.

I also just for fun blanked out my `chat.php` page and did a simple `echo "test";` just to make sure that it was not something with the `chat.php` page calling my DB and still had same results.

I am left with my javascript/Ajax code as the problem

Here is all my javascript/Ajax code. I added a <--------------> where the auto refresh code begins and calls `chat.php`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form#submit").submit(function() {
    var words = $('#words').attr('value');
    var my_file = $('#my_file').attr('value');
    var ip = '<?=$ip?>';
    var actual_link = '<?=$actual_link?>';
    var who = '<?=$user?>';
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "insert.php?",
            data: "words="+ words+
            "&my_file="+ my_file+
            "&ip="+ ip+
            "&actual_link="+ actual_link+
            "&who="+ who,
            success: function(data){
                $('#words').val('');
                $('#words').height(20);
                $('#send').replaceWith('<a href="logout.php?actual_link=<?=$actual_link?>" id="camera"><img src="/images/microphone.png" class="microphone"></a>');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
    $('#words').click(function() {
        $('#camera').replaceWith('<input type="image" src="/images/send.png" style="border:none; height:29px;" id="send"/>');
        return false;
    });
    //  changes mouse cursor when highlighting loawer right of box
    $("textarea").mousemove(function(e) {
        var $this = $(this);
        var myPos = $(this).offset();
        myPos.bottom = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        myPos.right = $(this).offset().left + $(this).outerWidth();

        if (myPos.bottom > e.pageY && e.pageY > myPos.bottom - 16 && myPos.right > e.pageX && e.pageX > myPos.right - 16) {
            $(this).css({ cursor: "nw-resize" });
        }
        else {
            $(this).css({ cursor: "" });
        }
    })
    //  the following simple make the textbox "Auto-Expand" as it is typed in
    .keydown(function(e) {
        //  the following will help the text expand as typing takes place
        while($(this).outerHeight() < this.scrollHeight) {
            $(this).height($(this).height()+1);
        };
    });
});
<-------------->
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function () {
    $('.chat').load('chat.php?actual_link=<?=$actual_link?>');
}, 3000); // refresh every 30000 milliseconds
<-------------->
var time = new Date().getTime();
$(document.body).bind("mousemove keypress", function(e) {
    time = new Date().getTime();
});

function refresh() {
    if(new Date().getTime() - time >= <?=$timeout?>) 
        window.location.replace('//<?=$redirect?>');
    else 
        setTimeout(refresh, 10000);
}

setTimeout(refresh, 10000);
```

UPDATE:

I have discovered that this issue is related to only ios 8 users when off wifi. Im getting closer to finding the answer and will update once again

Comment: It might happen that cellular operator is using caching proxy which somehow modifies / compresses the data received. Look at `console.log(data)`

Comment: What am I looking for exactly?

Comment: Check your chat.php for missing end tags.

Comment: @CesarBielich Sorry, you are not getting data by ajax, just submitting it there and updating by .load. Can you show the html source of the page and how the data looks on the server when send by ajax? The question to solve - do you receive data like this on the server or it is modified while it was sent to you back.

Comment: I have discovered that this is happening to all my websites under my hosting account with godaddy. So far I only know if this happening to me on an iPhone. I will get back a solution as soon as I find out what it is.